# search anchor tag from XML and get its href property

Tags: jquery

I need your help regarding extracting href text of an anchor (  ) tag. I have a XML shown below. I want to extract www.newyork.com and www.mumbai.com texts. I have tried multiple options but didnt work, Please help me to resolve.

```
  <world>   
      <usa>
        <location> New York </location>
        <websiteinfo> <p><a href="www.newyork.com"> This is new yorks site. </a></p></websiteinfo>
         ....   
       </usa>

      <india>
        <location> Mumbai </location>
        <websiteinfo> <p><a href="www.mumbai.com"> This is Mumbai's site. </a></p></websiteinfo>
         ....   
      </india> 
   </world>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `hre` instead of `href`. So try this:

```
$(worldXml).find("a[hre]").attr("hre");
```

Comment: Am sorry, it shud be href. :)

Comment: @jasper and you don't have a closing `</a>`

Comment: let me check ur solution. i have made necessary changes to XML.

Comment: @jasper try to check a count of anchors : `$(worldXml).find("a").length`